# How to deserialize json string to Apex

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

I have a requirement, where  I have to select some value from multipicklist and then send this json response to the server.

There are 2 scenarios:

1st Scenario:
when we are selecting and de-selecting by clicking the multipicklist. The response goes in a array.
`"country":["Arizona","Arkansas","Colorado"]` as a `List<String>`

2nd scenario:

When we select and de-select values manually (no Clicking), the response goes like below:
`"country":"Arizona;Arkansas; Colorado"`  as a Single `string`

```
    @RemoteAction
        global static String searchCountry(String jsonSearchCriteria) {

            try {
                CountrySearchCriteria crit = (CountrySearchCriteria)JSON.deserialize(    
                    jsonSearchCriteria, 
                    CountrySearchCriteria.class
                );

public class CountrySearchCriteria {

       public List<String> country;
```

1st Scenario works perfectly, because in the countruSearchCriteria we are deserializing with List, but when it is coming as single string, then it is throwing below error.

> You are trying decode an invalid JSON string, expected a List, but
>   found "Arizona;Arkansas; Colorado"

Is there any work around, where both scenario works perfectly?

Answer (score 2):

If suppose your json data is in string named jsonData then you can do like

```
Map<String, Object> mapOfJSONData = null;
List<string> countryList= null;

    if(jsonData.contains(';')){   //for 2nd scenario
        mapOfJSONData = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonData);
        string countries =(string) mapOfJSONData.get('country');
        countryList= countries.split(';');
    }else{ //for 1st scenario
       // your logic for 1st scenario
    }
```